# How to sort SMS message in listview android

Tags: android

> Can you help me please to sort SMS messages display in listView? I used SMS Broadcast Receiver and I want to display the new message to the top. I think I should use date to sort the item but I don't know how, Below is my sample code with image thank you!

[image]

> SMSReceiver.java

```
public static  final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) bundle.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMsg = "";
            String smsdate ="";
            SmsMessage smsMessage;
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; i++) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    String format = bundle.getString("format");
                    smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i], format);
                }
                else {
                    smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
                }
                String msgBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                Long msgDate = smsMessage.getTimestampMillis();
                
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(msgDate);
            Date finaldate = calendar.getTime();
            String smsDate = finaldate.toString();
            Calendar messageTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                smsMsg +=msgBody;
                smsdate += smsDate;
            }
                Receive_message inst = Receive_message.Instance();
                inst.receive_data(smsMsg,smsdate);
            }}}}
```

> Receive_message.java - Activity

```
 public void receive_data (final String smsMsg, String smsdate) {
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, list_items);
    text_listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.add(smsMsg);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an object that can be sorted easily like this.

```
 public static class MessageType {

    private String smsMsg;
    private String smsDate;

    public MessageType(String smsMsg, String smsDate) {
        this.smsMsg = smsMsg;
        this.smsDate = smsDate;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    public String getSmsMsg() {
        return smsMsg;
    }

    public void setSmsMsg(String smsMsg) {
        this.smsMsg = smsMsg;
    }

    public String getSmsDate() {
        return smsDate;
    }

    public void setSmsDate(String smsDate) {
        this.smsDate = smsDate;
    }

    public static Comparator<MessageType> ByDate = new Comparator<MessageType>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MessageType o1, MessageType o2) {
            return o1.smsDate.compareTo(o2.smsDate);
        }
    };

}
```

Change your ArrayList to this

```
    ArrayList<MessageType> list_items = new ArrayList<>();
```

And change your receive_data like this

```
    public void receive_data (final String smsMsg, String smsDate){

    list_items.add(new MessageType(smsMsg,smsDate));
    Collections.sort(list_items, MessageType.ByDate);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, list_items);
    text_listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also if the order is reversed you can change it here

```
return o1.smsDate.compareTo(o2.smsDate);
```

to this

```
return o2.smsDate.compareTo(o1.smsDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response but the output is always the same please help https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOqk3.jpg @eManuel